# How do I make Html.DisplayFor work in this case?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have this class:

```
  public class UserMessage
{
    public int UserMessageId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50)]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    public string Email { get; set; }


    [Required]
    public string MessageType { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(300)]
    [DataType(DataType.MultilineText)]
    public string Message { get; set; }


}
```

And in the view I have:

```
@model IEnumerable<Kekanto.Models.UserMessage>

@foreach (var message in Model)
{ 
@Html.DisplayFor(message)

}
```

I want to display the data in the view.... I donw know how to do in this case...
I know I can make @Html.DisplayFor(message=>message.Message) and write Display for all the fields... But I was wondering if I could make with a single comand

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
@{
   string str = "";
   foreach (var message in Model)
         { 
           str = str + message ;    
         } 
}
@Html.Raw(str)
```

Comment: that is a possible solution ,thx...
I found another one too....
@foreach (var message in Model)
{ 
@Html.DisplayFor(message1=> message)
}

Answer (score 1):

instead of using `DisplayFor` you can just use `Display`

```
@foreach (var message in Model)
{ 
    Html.Display(message)

}
```

But if you are just displaying data i would use something other than display maybe Html.Raw()

Comment: are you sure you want to use display

Answer (score 0):

How about some .net?

```
@string.Join(", ", Model.Select(T => T.Message))
```